# How to iterate over multiple function arguments?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use either locals() or *args to iterate over multiple function arguments. However, I am defining the function arguments as columns from a dataframe. How do I edit the following to have the float_format function iterate over a variable number of arguments?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd

def float_format(a, b, c, d, e, f): #Change to single *args function argument?
        for x in range(len(data[a])):
                data[a][x] = data[a][x].replace(' Mbps', '')
        for x in range(len(data[b])):
                data[b][x] = data[b][x].replace(' Mbps', '')
        for x in range(len(data[c])):
                data[c][x] = data[c][x].replace(' Mbps', '')                
        for x in range(len(data[d])):
                data[d][x] = data[d][x].replace(' Mbps', '')
        for x in range(len(data[e])):
                data[e][x] = data[e][x].replace(' Mbps', '')
        for x in range(len(data[f])):
                data[f][x] = data[f][x].replace(' Mbps', '')

file = r'Original_File.xls'
data = pd.read_excel(file, header=[2])

float_format('Average Receive bps',
               'Peak Receive bps',
               'Received Bandwidth',
               'Average Transmit bps',
               'Peak Transmit bps',
               'Transmit Bandwidth')

data.to_excel('results.xlsx', 'w+')
```

So if I try

```
def float_format(*iterate):
        for arg in iterate:
            for x in range(len(data[iterate])):
                    data[iterate][x] = data[iterate][x].replace(' Mbps', '')
```

I'm getting traceback errors over the way the function runs.

example df

```
>>> data
            Display Name Interface Name  ... Peak Transmit bps Transmit Bandwidth
0       1951 - LAB - FW1          port1  ...         0.56 Mbps         10.00 Mbps
1       1951 - LAB - FW1          port1  ...         0.37 Mbps         10.00 Mbps
2       1951 - LAB - FW1          port1  ...         0.34 Mbps         10.00 Mbps
3       1951 - LAB - FW1          port1  ...         0.36 Mbps         10.00 Mbps
4       1951 - LAB - FW1          port1  ...         0.83 Mbps         10.00 Mbps
5       1951 - LAB - FW1          port1  ...         0.55 Mbps         10.00 Mbps
6       1951 - LAB - FW1          port1  ...         0.27 Mbps         10.00 Mbps
7       1951 - LAB - FW1          port1  ...         0.41 Mbps         10.00 Mbps
8       1951 - LAB - FW1          port2  ...         0.00 Mbps       1000.00 Mbps
9       1951 - LAB - FW1          port2  ...         0.00 Mbps       1000.00 Mbps
10      1951 - LAB - FW1          port2  ...         0.00 Mbps       1000.00 Mbps
11      1951 - LAB - FW1          port2  ...         0.00 Mbps       1000.00 Mbps
12      1951 - LAB - FW1          port2  ...         0.00 Mbps       1000.00 Mbps
13      1951 - LAB - FW1          port2  ...         0.00 Mbps       1000.00 Mbps
14      1951 - LAB - FW1          port2  ...         0.19 Mbps       1000.00 Mbps
15      1951 - LAB - FW1          port2  ...         0.31 Mbps       1000.00 Mbps
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re trying to do?

Comment: You can make a list and iterate over `for i in [a,b,c,d,e,f]`. Or if you  want a *variadic* function, indeed use `*args`.

Comment: Exactly why don't you want to use `*args`?

Comment: @AMC I'm loading a spreadsheet as a dataframe. For a value in a column, the data is presented like "100 Mbps". So for a variable number of columns I'd like to take each string value and remove the " Mbps" so that I can perform calculations with the values. I have the float_format function currently taking the exact number of arguments as there are columns that I'm editing but I'd like to re-work this so that it can take a variable number of column arguments.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'd like to I just haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: Can you explain what the function is meant to do in the first place? It doesn't look very idiomatic.

Comment: @AMC the function takes one of the columns like 'Transmit Bandwidth' and for each value removes the part of the string that contains ' Mbps' with the .replace() method.

Comment: @cgarrido What value? That sounds quite simple, why does the function look so complex? Can you take a step back, and provide some more context for the operation?

Comment: @AMC take data['Transmit Bandwidth'] as an example. That column has values like "10.00 Mbps" for port1. I would like to find the transmit utilization percentage by taking the peak transmit and divide it by the available transmit bandwidth. I tried something quick like data['Transmit Bandwidth'] = data['Transmit Bandwidth'].astype(float) but it could not convert the string "10.00 Mbps" to a float. So the function was meant to iterate over every value in the range of the data['Transmit Bandwidth'] column and run a .replace() to remove the " Mbps" part of the string.

Comment: @cgarrido _So the function was meant to iterate over every value in the range of the data['Transmit Bandwidth'] column and run a .replace()_ Why not use the vectorized operations directly?

Comment: Are the strings which include the `'Mbps'` always in the same format? Could we simply slice off the last 5 characters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207210/discussion-between-cgarrido-and-amc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use *args or anything like that here, we can take advantage of the operations provided by Pandas.

---

#### Setup code

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col_1': np.random.randint(0, 10, 10),
                          'col_2': np.random.randint(0, 50, 10),
                          'col_3': np.random.randint(0, 5, 10)})

df_1[['col_1', 'col_3']] = df_1[['col_1', 'col_3']].astype(str) + ' Mbps'

print(df_1)
print(df_1.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
    col_1  col_2   col_3
0  1 Mbps     45  0 Mbps
1  2 Mbps     34  1 Mbps
2  6 Mbps     46  2 Mbps
3  7 Mbps      2  1 Mbps
4  6 Mbps     36  0 Mbps
5  9 Mbps     36  3 Mbps
6  4 Mbps     39  1 Mbps
7  4 Mbps     26  1 Mbps
8  1 Mbps     10  1 Mbps
9  6 Mbps      1  1 Mbps
col_1    object
col_2     int64
col_3    object
dtype: object
```

---

#### Method 1: `Series.str.extract()`

**Using a loop**

```py
cols_to_change = ['col_1', 'col_3']

for col_name in cols_to_change:
    df_1[col_name] = df_1[col_name].str.extract(r"(\d+) Mbps", expand=False).astype(int)
```

**Using `DataFrame.apply()`**

```py
cols_to_change = ['col_1', 'col_3']

df_1[cols_to_change] = df_1[cols_to_change].apply(lambda col: col.str.extract(r"(\d+) Mbps", expand=False)).astype(int)
```

---

#### Method 2: `Series.str.slice()`

**Using a loop**

```py
cols_to_change = ['col_1', 'col_3']

for col_name in cols_to_change:
    df_1[col_name] = df_1[col_name].str.slice(stop=-5).astype(int)
```

**Using `DataFrame.apply()`**

```py
cols_to_change = ['col_1', 'col_3']

df_1[cols_to_change] = df_1[cols_to_change].apply(lambda col: col.str.slice(stop=-5)).astype(int)
```

#### Result

DataFrame contents:

```
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      9     40      3
1      4      8      3
2      6     49      4
3      4     38      4
4      6     25      4
5      3      8      3
6      3     27      3
7      0     45      1
8      7     24      4
9      3     29      2
```

`dtypes`:

```
col_1    int64
col_2    int64
col_3    int64
dtype: object
```

---

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 4):

How about the following?

```
def test(*argv):
    for arg in argv:
            print(arg)

test('hello', 'world')
# hello
# world
```

Comment: I tried something similar in my edit but I get a pretty lengthy traceback when trying to use *args.

Comment: Can you please post the traceback?